# Issues with file splitting with c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I've been trying to make a program to split larger text files into smaller pieces so they are easier to work with.

I currently have two issues and cannot figure out what is going on.

Issue 1: The background worker will sometimes fire multiple times. I cannot seem to figure out why or how many times it decides to run. It will run the split and on the final file it seems like it loops back to the beginning of do work and run it again. It fires off multiple do work completed tasks as well. To complicate things if I set the number of files split to a different number I can get a different number of times the background worker seems to fire, but it doesn't directly correlate to the number of files. Sometimes the same number of files causes the background worker to fire only once and sometimes it fires multiple times.

Issue 2: Sometimes the split will not create all the files. With some files if I run it it will create the first two files and then drop the rest. Seems to only happen when I set the number to 3 files to split into. if I take the line count and add it up it should equal out correctly. So i'm not sure what is going on there.

**Calling Thread**

```
private void StartSplit()
    {
        if (int.TryParse(NumberOfFilesTB.Text, out _numberOfFiles))
        {
            if (bg.IsBusy)
            {
                ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).SetStatus("Warning",
                    "Please only run one split process at a time.");
                return;
            }

            ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).DisplayAlert(
                "Split is running, you will receive an alert when it has finished. You may use other tools while the split is running.");

            var args = new List<string> { _filepath, _includeHeaders.ToString(), _numberOfFiles.ToString() };
            bg.DoWork += bg_DoWork;
            bg.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bg.ProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
            bg.RunWorkerCompleted += bg_RunWorkerCompleted;
            bg.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bg.RunWorkerAsync(args);
            ProcessText.Text = "Running split process";
        }
        else
        {
            ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).SetStatus("Warning", "Please enter a number for number of files");
        }
    }
```

**Background Thread**

```
  private void bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var args = e.Argument as List<string>;
        string filepath = args[0];
        string includeHeaders = args[1];
        int numberOfFiles = Convert.ToInt32(args[2]);
        int numberOfRows = _lineCount / numberOfFiles;
        _tempath = Path.GetDirectoryName(_filepath);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(_tempath+"\\split");

        if (includeHeaders == "True")
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(filepath)))
            {
                _lines.Clear();
                _header = reader.ReadLine();
                _lines.Add(_header);

                for (int i = 0; i < _lineCount; i++)
                {

                    if (bg.CancellationPending)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    int percentage = (i + 1) * 100 / _lineCount;

                    bg.ReportProgress(percentage);

                    _lines.Add(reader.ReadLine());

                    if (i % numberOfRows == 0)
                    {
                        _counter++;
                        Debug.WriteLine(i);

                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            //skip first iteration 
                            _counter = 0;
                            continue;

                        }
                        _output = _tempath + "\\" + "split\\" + _fileNoExt + "_split-" + _counter + _fileExt;
                        _filesMade.Add(_output);
                        File.WriteAllLines(_output, _lines.ConvertAll(Convert.ToString));
                        _lines.Clear();
                        _lines.Add(_header);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(filepath)))
            {
                _lines.Clear();
                _header = reader.ReadLine();
                _lines.Add(_header);
                for (int i = 0; i < _lineCount; i++)
                {
                    if (bg.CancellationPending)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    int percentage = (i + 1) * 100 / _lineCount;
                    bg.ReportProgress(percentage);
                    _lines.Add(reader.ReadLine());

                    if (i % numberOfRows == 0)
                    {
                        _counter++;

                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            //skip first iteration
                            _counter = 0;
                            continue;
                        }
                        string output = _tempath + "\\" + "split\\" + _fileNoExt + "_split-" + _counter + _fileExt;
                        _filesMade.Add(_output);
                        File.WriteAllLines(output, _lines.ConvertAll(Convert.ToString));
                        _lines.Clear();

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

**Run Worker Completed**

```
private void bg_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            StopSplit();
            _filesMade.Clear();
            ProcessText.Text = "Split cancelled";
            return;
        }
        _filesMade.Clear();
        ProcessText.Text = "Split has completed, click here to open the directory";
    }
```

Comment: You're subscribing to events but never unsubscribing.

Comment: Bad program design. You have 2 sections with almost identical code. Currently searching for the reason of failure #2...

Comment: If you have feedback to what I could improve on, i'm all ears. I'm still rather new to this and events and best programming practices are still somewhat of a new concept to me.

Comment: It's also bad practice to start variable names with _ . If they are member variables, I suggest m_, which I prefer and use.

Comment: Furthermore,  you should avoid 'global' variables. Narrow down the scope of variables as much as possible or sensible. Prefer local variables. If a variable is needed somewhere else, pass it to the function as an argument, which is more difficult but safer.

Comment: Avoid variable names like i. You cannot search for them! http://www.makinggoodsoftware.com/2009/05/04/71-tips-for-naming-variables/  search the intranet for 'programming tips' or 'code conventions'

Comment: Tobias, why is it bad practice? Microsoft specifically says not to do it.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @IanP, not to do what?

Comment: @TobiasKnauss sorry, that was in reference to "It's also bad practice to start variable names with _ . If they are member variables, I suggest m_, which I prefer and use." That is what Microsoft specifically recommends against.

Comment: @IanP, if they do, I don't understand why. At least for me it's very useful. I know immediately when seeing `m_abcd`, that this is a member of my class.  `abcd` instead is local. `msc_iAbcd` is a member, static const, integer. For letters that show me scope, type and other properties... I call this helpful.

Comment: Their recommended convention is _name for fields, PropertyName for properties and parameterName for parameters. The thought is that you have Intellisense to tell you what the names don't.

Comment: What if you are not using VisualStudio? What if Intellisense fails again like it does regularly? I am using VS 2008 and 2015, but I don't rely on products of MS. That would cost me too much time and nerves. Also, it's easier for other people to get into the code. Always make work as easy and productive as possible, and that's my way to achieve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet your BgW is a member of your class...
In Startsplit() you add a new callback each time this function is executed.
   That's why it runs multiple times.

Other answer after dinner.

Finished dinner...
your method of counting is faulty in multiple ways:
1) If you are missing files, I bet it's the last one. E.g. 30 lines, 3 files:
`i % numberOfRows` is zero at i=0, 10, 20, but i does not reach 30.
2) you are missing lines, e.g. 31 lines 4 files:
Files are saved at i=7, 14, 21, 28. Lines 29-31 are missing.

I suggest you use a nested for loop, outer one for files,  inner one for lines, and improve your calculation. And put all your lists and counters inside the function!
I hope you appreciate my answer. I hate typing on a tablet.  But also didn't want to start my computer just for this... ;-)

Comment: Correct. I declared the BgW as a member of the class so that way I could call into it for progress or cancel that BgW when needed. 

I'm not sure how I would use a BgW in a method and still be able to call it from a different method since it wouldn't exist outside that scope, correct?

Comment: @Tbooty, yes, correct, so you should also CONFIGURE it at the place you created it.